# A bunch of bundle files generated due to shared components

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am currently migrating a web application based in jQuery to Vue.js. To do it progressive, I am creating a different app per each module.

After build the code, there is a common file:

```
assets/js/vendors.d2c6c799.js
```

And each app has its own file:

```
assets/js/admin/dashboard.5c4be0d8.js
assets/js/admin/users.5c4be0d8.js
assets/js/alerts/main.5c4be0d8.js
.....
```

Up here everything perfect. The problem is that if those applications use same general components, another files are generated like:

```
assets/js/admin/dashboard~users/users.c3cbae3a.js
assets/js/admin/users~main/users.c3cbae3a.js
assets/js/alerts/dashboard~main/dashboard.c3cbae3a.js
assets/js/alerts/users~main/main.c3cbae3a.js
.....
```

That is a bit annoying and confused. I would like to each application has their own files, or all shared components in the same js file, but not generate a bunch of js files like in the above example.
Is that possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since webpack 4 configs automatically split shared modules out into their own chunks.

You can change this behaviour via the `optimization.splitChunks` configuration property ([docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/)).

To disable the default splitting behaviour altogether set the `default` and `vendor` cache groups to false:

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            default: false,
            vendor: false,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just found another way to fix it. Into splitChunks, I have changed "chunks=all" by "chunks=async". But I don't know if it is too much recommended